# Python module logging not working with paho-mqtt loop_forever()

Tags: python, oop, logging, mqtt, paho

I'm writing a project focused on receiving and processing messages from a MQTT broker using paho-mqtt in python. The main project files are:

```
│   main.py
│   message_processor.py
│   mqtt_project.log
│   subscriber.py
│   utils.py
```

The problem is that the logger defined within message_processor.py, which is responsible for most of the logging, is not working.

```
### message_processor.py ###
from utils import setup_logging

class MessageProcessor:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        ...
        self.config = load_config("config.yaml")
        self.logger = setup_logging(__name__)

    def process_message(self, message) -> list[dict] | None:
        topic = message.topic
        payload = message.payload.decode()
        self.logger.debug("Received message from topic: %s, payload: %s", topic, payload) # This does not log
```

Despite being defined the exact same way, the logger from subscriber.py works as expected

```
### subscriber.py ###
from message_processor import MessageProcessor

class MessageSubscriber:
    def __init__(self, message_processor:MessageProcessor) -> None:
        self.message_processor = message_processor
        self.client = self.create_client()
        self.logger = setup_logging(__name__)

    def on_message(self, client, userdata, message):
        self.logger.debug("Received message from topic: %s, payload: %s", message.topic, message.payload) # This logs normally
        items = self.message_processor.process_message(message) # This should generate log, but it does not
```

This is how I run the project in the **main.py** file:

```
from utils import load_config
from subscriber import MessageSubscriber
from message_processor import MessageProcessor

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = load_config()
    sample_rate_ms = config['sample_rate_ms']

    processor = MessageProcessor(sample_rate_ms, 500)
    subscriber = MessageSubscriber(processor)

    subscriber.connect_client()
    subscriber.client.loop_forever(retry_first_connection=True)
```

Is there a way to make the logger on message_processor.py work?

The logs are generated normally if I call them inside the __init__(self) method. That means that when I instantiate the MessagaProcessor on the main.py file, it works as expected, but when the MessageProcessor methods are called inside the loop_forever(), they don't show up on the log file.

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (i.e. include a definition for `setup_logging` etc). It would also be helpful if you could expand on "is not working" (is nothing output? what happens if you try a `print()` etc). Try calling `subscriber.on_message()` from main and see what is output.